# How to resolve this error `Refused to load media from 'blob:https://...' `in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services, speech-synthesis

I am developing a chrome extension that utilizes 'microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk' to convert the selected text on any webpage into speech. The core code of this chrome extension is below:

```
import { SpeakerAudioDestination } from "microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk";
import { getSettings } from "./utils/setting";
let player: SpeakerAudioDestination | null = null;
export const textToSpeech = async (
  text
) => {
  if (player) {
    player.pause();
    player.close();
  }
  const voiceName = await getSettings("voice");
  return new Promise( async(resolve, reject) => {    
    const voiceName =  await getSettings("voice");    
    const speechConfig = window.SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(...);
    speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "...";
    speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName = voiceName;
    player = new  window.SpeechSDK.SpeakerAudioDestination();
    const audioConfig =  window.SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromSpeakerOutput(player);
    const speechSynthesizer = new window.SpeechSDK.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
    speechSynthesizer.speakTextAsync(
      text,
      result => {
        resolve(result);
        speechSynthesizer.close();
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error);
        speechSynthesizer.close();
      }
    );
  });
};
```

However, I encountered an issue where some websites have set up Content Security Policy that prevents the extension from playing speech. For example, the error message below enclosed in [] is from a specific website:

[Refused to load media from 'blob:https://developer.mozilla.org/57fb5680-66f6-49f8-b953-0fb9f2b140df' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "media-src 'self' archive.org videos.cdn.mozilla.net".]

How can I solve this?
If the SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromSpeakerOutput(player) method generates a blob URL that violates the webpage's security policy, is there another way to resolve this issue? For instance, can we use audio stream playback instead? I am not very familiar with this area.

Comment: It happens if you specify the content script's `world` as MAIN (try not doing it) or the sdk runs its code via a DOM `script` element, in which case the only solutions are to overwrite/remove the CSP header of the site or run the sdk inside a `web_accessible_resources` iframe (it's created by the content script; look for examples).

Answer (score 0):

> I followed the  [GitHub-document](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/js-e2e-express-server-cognitive-services) with same code, I can able to convert the selected text on a webpage into speech.

**Code:**

```js
const { textToSpeech } = require('./azure-cognitiveservices-speech');
const express = require('express');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const path = require('path');
const utils = require('./utils');
const create = async () => {
    const app = express();
    app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, '../public', 'favicon.ico')));
    app.use(utils.appLogger);
    app.get('/text-to-speech', async (req, res, next) => {
        const { key, region, phrase, file } = req.query;
        if ("key" || "region" || "Hi, kamali. How are you?") res.status(404).send('Invalid query string');
        let fileName = null;
        if (file && file === true) {
            fileName = `./temp/stream-from-file-${timeStamp()}.mp3`;
        } 
    const audioStream = await textToSpeech(key, region, phrase, fileName);
    res.set({
        'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
        'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
    });
    audioStream.pipe(res);
});
    app.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
        res.json({hello: 'goodbye'});
        res.end();
    });
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/client.html'));
    });
    app.use(utils.logErrors);
    app.use(utils.clientError404Handler);
    app.use(utils.clientError500Handler);
    app.use(utils.errorHandler);
    return app;
};
module.exports = {
    create
};
```

**Output:**
**Local output:**
[image]

With the above port, I can hear the speech of the text in the browser:
[image]